# What is the right permission to allow users to kick other users

Tags: permissions

I want that our content managers can kick other users which are logged in into sitecore. When I call the site with my admin account I see the Users that are logged in and I can kick them. But the normal content managers is not seeing any users. Is there a specific role I can assign to them that they can kick other users or is this a admin feature only?

Comment: SPE comes with an Elevated Unlock feature. Just add the users to a specific role and they will see the option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Sitecore code comments:

> When a user logs in, Sitecore checks if the maximum number of users has been reached (as specified in the license). If so, the logout user web page is shown allowing the user to logout a existing session.

There is a flag in Sitecore settings called `AllowLogoutOfAllUsers` which is set to `false` by default.

If this flag is set to `false` users can only kick their own sessions from other browsers. And administrator can kick everyone.

If this flag is set to `true`, users can kick everyone else.

```
<!--
  ALLOW LOGOUT OF ALL USERS
            Indicates if the logout screen presents all users or
            just users with the same name

-->
<setting name="AllowLogoutOfAllUsers" value="false"/>
```